# Image opened from stream is different from opened from file

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have 2 pieces of sample codes, I try to do the same thing that update property items back to image and save it under a different file.

Code 1

```
        Image image;
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(this.fileName, FileMode.Open)) {
            image = Image.FromStream(stream);
            foreach (var property in this.propItems) {
                image.SetPropertyItem(property);
            }
        }

        image.Save(@"D:\Temp\1.jpg");
        image.Dispose();
```

Code 2

```
        using (Image image = new Bitmap(this.fileName)) {
            foreach (var property in this.propItems) {
                image.SetPropertyItem(property);
            }

            image.Save(@"D:\Temp\1.jpg");
        }
```

The only difference is that how I opened the file. If I run the first piece of code I got exception message

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException was unhandled
>   HResult=-2147467259   Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
>   Source=System.Drawing   ErrorCode=-2147467259

My 2nd piece of code just runs fine, I can get proper output. What is the difference here?

Comment: In the first sample you've left the using scope and the stream is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design, the MSDN article for Image.FromStream() sternly warns about this.  Once you close the stream, the image is no longer usable.  And trying to save it like you do is very likely, but not guaranteed, to throw an exception when it tries to retrieve pixel data from a closed stream.

A key property of the Image class is that it is *lazy*, not unlike many .NET classes, it won't access the stream data until necessary.  And it isn't necessary until the pixel data is actually used, that happens in the Save() call in your snippet.  Kaboom when it can no longer read it.

You can fix your first snippet by moving the Save() call inside the *using* statement:

```
    using (var stream = new FileStream(this.fileName, FileMode.Open)) 
    using (var image = Image.FromStream(stream) {
        foreach (var property in this.propItems) {
            image.SetPropertyItem(property);
        }
        image.Save(@"D:\Temp\1.jpg");
    }
```

No point in using a FileStream anymore.  Do note that the file that you save the image to cannot be the same file that you read the image from.  Some hint that you tried to work around that problem.  Using a MemoryStream is a common technique to avoid the lock on the file.

Also note another bug in your code, you save the file with the .jpg extension but it is actually a PNG.  You cannot omit the ImageFormat argument if you want a JPEG.